# include and require_once not work when I upload the php file to server

Tags: php, rest

I create an Api by php using restler library 
its work well in my PC but when I upload database and my Api file to server isn't give me JSON 
after many attempts I discovered I can't access to any file I `include` it or `require_once` 
but I need that for include restler library, this is make api not work
What I should do to access?

also my api should return to me Arabic json
I use this line to do that

```
$link = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=---;charset=utf8','---','---')
```

its work in my PC but on server No :(

Comment: is it showing any error in console?

Answer (score 0):

I assume your PC is a Windows PC, and the server is running Linux.

The file system on Linux is case-sensitive, whereas Windows is not.

Check the path that you are `include`ing or `require`ing and make sure that the file exists on the server exactly as you are trying to include it.

```
// Real file path = /some/path/My-file.php

include '/some/path/my-file.php'; // Won't work
include '/some/path/My-file.php'; // Will work
```

Also, ensure you are not using a path that looks like 'C://some/path' as the file system on Linux is not structured in the same way as it is on Linux.

Without seeing the actual errors you are getting, this is the best I can do.